# Three step Approval Workflow SharePoint 2013 Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, task-list

What I want: 
I want to create workflow on list which contain three steps approval process. When task is approved then next level task will be created and if it is rejected then previous level task is again activated and next level task will not created.

Example: Item Inserted into list and First Task is created.

Tasks1:  for Emaployee  Approved/Rejected then create next

Tasks2:  for Superior   Approved/Rejected then create next else reassign to Emaployee

Tasks3:  for Manager  Approved/Rejected then create next else reassign to Superior

Also I want:
I have used customization setting of workflow but that approval is content approval **Require content approval for submitted items**  but I want Approval Process like SharePoint 2010 in SharePoint 2013
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To can go back in workflow, you should use `stages` and `transition to stage` at SharePoint 2013 workflow  Platform by doing the following

**Steps**

- Create a list workflow with SharePoint 2013 workflow Platform.
- Create Three Stage as something like the following based on your requirements

**Note :** تمت الموافقة = Approved

[image]
[image]

Comment: This answer is helpful for me. and I have created this workflow but I am unable to find task approval in task list as **end user**. where to approve it. In SharePoint 2010, we can approve task to click on title of the task and approval window opens. and in SharePoint 2013 i didn't find approval window.

Comment: Dear @MohitSikhwal I am sorry for late , when you click on workflow in SharePoint designer , you will find customization section that has our task list , task history . at task list you can find all tasks related to this workflow, also , when you assign task it should receive an email to approve or reject it , also after you publish your workflow it will add a new column with the workflow name that has the current status when you click on it. you can show the details of the current task and wait to approve for "xxx" , please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification

Comment: I have Edited my question also I have put image that I want in approval process. Please have look of my edited question.

Comment: What I know, when you assign a task it should appear as Task Form https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/00/67/02/metablogapi/8666.image_thumb_52099D2D.png  not like default approve  , meanwhile, you can customize your task form as mentioned at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2012/09/14/how-to-manipulate-the-task-form-with-sharepoint-designer-for-new-task-actions/  also I suggest to you to ask this new request at new question to can get more answers

Comment: OK I have put it on new question please check it also.   http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194131/how-to-approve-task-in-sharepoint-online-2013