# How to approve task in SharePoint Online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow2013

I am unable to find option to approve/reject task in the task list where task is created from SharePoint workflow 2013. I have Found 
**Require content approval for submitted items** this only. and with this approval task cannot go on next level of task approval.
What I want: Same as SharePoint workflow 2010  [image]

I want in SharePoint workflow 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I find another way to approve SharePoint 2013 task to approve. 
First click on task and then edit it.

[image]

After that you will have approval window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `Content Approval Process` is no longer exist in SharePoint Designer 2013 with SharePoint 2013 workflow platform,

This is due to the Workflow form changed **from InfoPath form to ASPX form**, For more details check SharePoint Designer section at [SharePoint Server 2013 known issues](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Server-2013-known-issues-780242a6-236e-4d7a-8379-118a1aaa2a51?CorrelationId=f7b0b3a3-f817-49d6-bb02-6457b71f5e98&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102919021#__sharepoint_designer_1)

But , I have one suggestion for you, you can combine the SharePoint 2010 workflow with SharePoint 2013 workflow as the following:

- Create A SharePoint 2010 approval workflow that contains the content approval task form .
- At your SharePoint 2013 workflow,Instead of creating `Start Task Process` at SharePoint 2013 Workflow action , try to add an action that is `Start a List workflow` at this list on the current item .

[image]

For more details check [How to trigger a SharePoint 2010 workflow from a SharePoint 2013 workflow](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2012/08/17/how-to-trigger-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-from-a-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)